# How to change the character on post-new.php and profile.php

Tags: wordpress

It is a question about the WordPress administration screen.
I'd like to change the character on `post-new.php` and `profile.php`. I do not know which part of the array should be changed. that's why I am not to use JavaScript.
Please let me know if you know.

The first one is to change the 'publish' button on `post-new.php`, and completion message or update message after pressing the button.

The second is to change each label and 'Update Profile' button on `profile.php`, and alert message and completion message after pressing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below code into your current active theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'modify_button_name_and_message', 10, 2 );

function modify_button_name_and_message( $translation, $text ) {
 if ( $text == 'Publish' ){
   return 'Save Post';
 }
 if ( $text == 'Update Profile' ){
   return 'Save Profile';
 }
 if ( $text == 'Profile updated.' ){
   return 'Profile Successfully Update.';
 }
 if ( $text == 'Post updated.' ){
   return 'Post Is Successfully Updated.';
 }
 if ( $text == 'Post published.' ){
   return 'Post Is Successfully Created.';
 }
 return $translation;
}
```

**Note : All Changes you done in any file of theme are gone when you update theme. So prefer [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)**.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I am able to solve the problem thanks to you. This way is very useful as it can be applied elsewhere.